# How to set a javascript function to onchange action in boostrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

This is my boostrap drop down query.

```
        <div id="drop">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1"id="mymenu">
                        <%
                            try {
                                ResultSet r = DB.JDBC.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select name from item ");
                                while (r.next()) {
                        %>
                        <li role="presentation" id="menu2" ><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"><%=r.getString("name")%></a></li>

                        <%
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (DB.JDBC.getConnection() != null) {
                                    DB.JDBC.getConnection().close();
                                }
                            }
                        %>
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

It search item name in db. Now I want to do even when it's value clicked. I tried a code. But no output.

```
    <script >
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#drop').change(function(event) {
                var $name =  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
               alert($name);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

I searched boostrap description also. But couldn't find an answer please help me.

Comment: Looking at your html code I don't see the ` $('#drop')` selector. You didn't added or the change method should be bind to another element?

Comment: @andybeli can u see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear as to what you are trying to achieve when a value from the dropdown is clicked, but assuming you are looking for an event that will be triggered each time someone clicks an item from the dropdown you could try something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mymenu li').click(
    function (clickedItem) {
        alert(clickedItem.currentTarget.innerText); 
        //do other stuff
    });
});
```

You can see a demo of this solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6449/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Ok wait. Please pardon me. I'm @ office. Please give me sometime. If you don't mind, I'm stuck with other issues too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry I couldn't accepted this before.